# Different gravity in each ListView row

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` representing messages between 2 people. I'm trying to set `Gravity` to `LEFT` or `RIGHT` according to the sender (say *me* / *them*).

This what I'm currently doing:

```
conversationListAdapter.add(message,true/*me*/);
```

and:

```
conversationListAdapter.add(message,false/*them*/);
```

In the adapter:

```
public void add(String object , boolean fromMe) {
    super.add(object);
    this.fromMe = fromMe;
}
```

`fromMe` is a variable in the adapter itself.

And inisde `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(convertView == null) {...}
String entry = conversationList.get(position);
if(entry != null) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    if(fromMe) {
        holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
    else {
        holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    holder.message.setText(entry);
}
```

What's happening is when I send a message, all rows set their gravity to `RIGHT`, and when I receive a message, they all set their gravity to `LEFT`.

How to do this independently for each row?

I thought maybe move the variable to the `holder`? But then how can I assign it?

Or have 2 different rows (one with `LEFT` gravity and one with `RIGHT` gravity), and inflate each of them accordingly?

**EDIT:**

`xml` of row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_convo_row_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Comment: paste the xml of the row.

Comment: can you create to views separately and as per sender or receiver set visibility

Comment: @EE66 Added. Please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Seperate class for storing data like below.**

```
public class ChatMessages{
    private String message;
    private boolean isMe;

    public ChatMessages(String message, boolean isMe){
      this.message=message;
      this.isMe=isMe;
}
}
```

Store each item values in this Chatmessages object and retreive,

**Then you will be fine.**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this has something to do with your `fromMe` variable within your adapter. Your `add()` method likely causes the `ListView` to redraw, all using the same `fromMe` variable.

Therefore you need to store the individual senders with each message. I am assuming that right now you are using a `List<String>` data structure, you need to find a way to store the sender with each String. One way to do this is by creating a class for messages.

Example pseudocode:

```
class Message{
    public boolean sentFromMe;
    public String message;
    public Message(String message, boolean sentFromMe){
        this.sentFromMe = sentFromMe;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Then create a `List<Message>`, and in your `getView()`:

```
Message entry = conversationList.get(position);
if(entry != null) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    if(entry.sentFromMe) {
        holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
    else {
        holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    holder.message.setText(entry.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could crate a class that represents a list item. The XML is fine.

The class could look something like this:

```
public class ConversationLine {

    public final String message;
    public final boolean sentByMe;

    public ConversationLine(String message, boolean sentByMe) {
        this.message = message;
        this.sentByMe = sentByMe;
    }

}
```

Using an ArrayAdapter, that could look like this:

```
public class ConversationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ConversationLine> {

    public EndpointAdapter(Context context, List<ConversationLine> conversationLines) {
        super(context, R.layout.your_layout, conversationLines);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_convo_row_textview;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        ConversationLine entry = conversationList.get(position);
        if(entry != null) {
            if(entry.sentByMe) {
                holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            else {
                holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            }
            holder.message.setText(entry);
        }
    }

    private static class Holder {

        final TextView message;
    }
}
```

Then, you can add items to the adapter, using the standard `add()` methods of the ArrayAdapter.

*Note*: This code might not compile correctly, written by hand ;)

*Edit*: Improved code, Forgot to assign TextView to Holder.message